# Regular Expression find the all strings that start at the beginning of line with integer and end at the end of line with word

Tags: regex

```
^[0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z]+$
```

I have written the above RE for the question which is: Write an RE for all strings that start at the beginning of line with an integer and ends at the end of line with a word, but I am not sure if its correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why would you need the middle part. You could just drop it and accept any chars between the required parts.

Looks like

```
^[0-9].+[a-zA-Z]+$
```

will do the job, if the word is considered to be at least one alphabet symbol.

In case if you want a word to be at least two alphabet symbols, you could use `{2,}` instead of last `+`.

Comment: In almost all NFA regex engines, `^[0-9].+[a-zA-Z]+$` won't match a string that contains line break(s).

Comment: @Wiktor OP hasn't specified that they need multi-line. In fact, they specified the opposite - "start at the beginning of line with an integer and ends at the end of line with a word".

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood though. Anyway, `([\n\r]|.)+` instead of `.+` should do the trick with matching multiple lines, right?

Comment: Never use `([\n\r]|.)+`, it will either cause stack overflow (as in Java) or will cause the code to execute very slowly. Use the `s` modifier (or `m` in Ruby), or `[\s\S]` workaround.

Comment: @Wiktor Thanks for that! Didn't know. I was referring JS, and here `([\n\r]|.)+` doesn't seem to work slower than any other regex.